# how to run my web link with "http" , not with "https" . could someone please help me to do this ?. my source code is added below

Tags: java, android, webview

This Java code is a part of my Android Studio project, where I'm facing a specific challenge. I need to load a website using the "http" protocol, rather than the more secure "https" protocol. To accomplish this, I've utilized the Android WebView component, which allows embedding web content within the application. However, I've encountered issues with this task. please help me

```
package com.example.chatgpt;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Build;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36";
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // Enable JavaScript support if needed

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        }

        // Load the URL of the website you want to display
        webView.loadUrl("http://weburl.com/");
    }

    // Override onBackPressed to handle WebView navigation
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you explain what is the issue, maybe someone will be able to actually help.

Comment: It depends on the site you're loading. If it supports plain `http` (which it shouldn't, it's 2023), then it will just load over http. If it doesn't, then it'll probably forward you to the `https` variant (which is the correct thing to do).

Comment: thank you for the reply . I get this error "net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED"